# How to minimize a function using vectors as input?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm learning Mathematica and meet a problem. Here is a simple example.

```
x = {0, 0.5, 1}
y = {a-3,b,10}
yl= {b,a,5}
```

I want to find the value of a and b when it minimum of (y-x)^2+(yl-x)^2

```
Nminimize[(y - x)^2 + (yl - x)^2, {a,b}]
```

But it returns

```
Minimize[{(-3. + a)^2 + (0. + b)^2, (-0.5 + a)^2 + (-0.5 + b)^2, 97.}, {a, b}]
```

What's the right way to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: I don't think I understand this at all. When `a` is 1, `y1 - y` is zero right?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26

Comment: Can you give a minimal example of what you are trying to do? This is not clear enough for people to help you.

Comment: Also note that `NMinimize` is case sensitive and you are showing Nminimize.

Comment: I rewrite the example, I think it is clear now, thank you guys

Comment: How do you want to compare the vectors to determine which is smallest? Is `{1, 2, 3}` smaller than `{0, 0, 10}`? In my opinion, the usual way would be to compare the `Norm`s of the vectors. The `Norm` of a vector would return a scalar value, and these scalar values can be easily compared.

Comment: The expression `(y - x)^2 + (yl - x)^2` is vector-valued. A vector cannot be minimized, only a scalar can. Perhaps you misunderstood Mathematica notation. If `vec = {x,y,z}`, then `vec^2` is `{x^2, y^2, z^2}`. If you want `x^2 + y^2 + z^2`, then use `Norm[vec]^2` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in [`NMinimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html) and it will require the objective function to be a scalar and not a vector.  You could minimize the [`Norm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Norm.html) of the vector like so.

```
x = {0, 0.5, 1};
y = {a - 3, b, 10};
yl = {b, a, 5};
NMinimize[(y - x)^2 + (yl - x)^2 // Norm, {a, b}]
(* {97.0272, {a -> 1.75, b -> 0.25}} *)
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you!